While loop doesn't work inside class method
I am a Javascript novice, while solving an exercise I got to a assignment I can't figure out,
here is the exercise:

Redo All
Let's say we wanted to redo all of our undos. We could just keep
redo-ing all of undo operations until we had to stop. At what point
would we stop?  We stop when the stack is empty! Remember we have an
appropriately named function on our stack for just that reason.
Your
Goal: Implement Redo All
Let's go ahead and implement redoAll where we keep redo-ing until we
have no more undos left.

I know I could peek and look at the solution but I am asking you guys because I don't understand why my code doesn't work.
Here's my code:
const { MAX_STACK_SIZE } = require('./config');

class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  push(item) {
    if (MAX_STACK_SIZE > this.items.length) {
      this.items.push(item)
    } else throw new Error("Error");
  }
  pop() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("Error")
    }
    return this.items.pop();
  }
  isEmpty() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) return true;
    return false;
  }
  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1]
  }
}

module.exports = Stack;

const Stack = require('./Stack');

class OperationManager {
  constructor() {
    this.operations = new Stack();
    this.undos = new Stack();
  }

  addOperation(operation) {
    this.operations.push(operation);
  }

  undo() {
    this.undos.push(this.operations.pop())
  }

  redo() {
    this.operations.push(this.undos.pop())
  }

  redoAll() {
    while (true) {
      if (this.undos.length != 0) {
        this.operations.push(this.undos.pop())
      } else false;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = OperationManager;

My solution for redoAll() is to loop in this.undos (which I thought it would be an array, but apparently it isn't) and to remove elements one by one until it's empty. I've tried this with a "for...of" loop and it doesn't work either.
this is what I wrote:
for(i of this.undos) {
  if(this.undos.length != 0) {
    this.operations.push(i)&&this.undos.pop(i)
  }  
}

It says:

this.undos is not iterable.

There must be something that I am not understanding here. All the methods in both classes are written by me and gave passing results in the previous part of the exercise, I am wondering if there is a mistake there.

You have to be careful when modifying something you're iterating over. while(true) will just create an infinite loop unless you provide a way to break out of it with break or throwing an error. Also, it doesn't look like Stack is iterable. See Iterators and Generators for details

What is else false supposed to mean or do?

There's no length property on Stack elements like undos (or operations, for that matter). This is likely what is causing your code to misbehave at run time.

for(i of this.undos) { ... } does not work because undos is a stack and not an array.

this.undos.length will be undefined, because your implementation of Stack does not include a length property. So then this.undos.length != 0  will evaluate to true (because undefined != 0) thus, you will always try to pop from undos and will sooner or later create an error, when you try to pop from an empty stack. A simple solutioin to that, would be using the isEmpty() instead of length. But that still will leave you with an endless loop, because you have no way of exiting your while(true)

The first thing I would recommend is to learn how to use your browser's debugging tools. This would highlight many of the problems you are hitherto unaware of and will be the best use of your time in becoming a better programmer.

What you want is while (!this.undos.isEmpty()). You don't need the if statement, since that checks the length of the stack.

Also, your Stack.push method is wrong in the assumption that an error should be thrown. When the stack is full, you should implement a FIFO, and remove old entries from the beginning of array as you push new ones in.

@RokoC.Buljan Whether a stack (or any other collection) throws an error or discards an element (by whatever selection strategy) upon reaching the defined maximum size depends totaly on the given usecase and/or the developers choice. Neither of those stategies is per se "correct" or "wrong" ... I personally tend to raise an error in such a case instead of silenty throwing away (potentially crucial) data ...

Thank you guys, in the end, this answer fixed it:  "What you want is while (!this.undos.isEmpty()). You don't need the if statement, since that checks the length of the stack. –
Barmar"

If you used a debugger (always do it) or simply look thoroughly, you would see a trivial infinite loop bug (you never break out of your loop, neither conditionally nor unconditionally) and a simple fix:
while (this.undos.length > 0)
    this.operations.push(this.undos.pop());

As to your question, the answer is simple: not all objects are iterable with for… of, but Array objects can do it. (More generally, objects, implementing [Symbol.iterator].)
By the way, you could solve your problem with simple [] arrays as well, without a Stack object, as I've shown in the above sample. At the same time, all objects, including simple {} objects can be iterated using for… in:
for (let value of array) // arrays
    console.log(value);

for (let index in someObject)  // all objects
    console.log(`Index: ${index}, value: ${someObject[index]}`);
// It is possible to do the same to Array objects, but why?
// For... in is not the same: it iterates object properties,
// but only so-called enumerable properties,
// and, in general case, property values are obtained from getters


Except you should never use for...in on iterables, only on objects. The syntax iterates over all enumerable string properties, which is not the same as "all indexed elements", and can lead to hilarious bugs when you use it with arrays.

I agree. Iterable is specifically designed to iterate with for... of, it would look pointless. And I never advised that. Array in my sample is merely the object name, and not a type. The idea is that Array is an object, but an object does not have to be an array. So, it's not "except" — you cannot possibly give all possible pieces of advise in one answer. Anyway, you brought up a good point.

Your second code block advocates using it with arrays. It really shouldn't, because it is not doing what the words for index in array suggests. It is not iterating over each index in an array, so showing code like this at best misleading, but at worst teaches someone bad habits =)

Your second code block advocates using it with arrays. No. Actually, iterating an array in a "wrong" way is useful enough for learning purposes, it does not mean advocating.  And I never said the iterations are the same. However, I guess I should better clarify the answer, to avoid misunderstanding and wrong practice, so thank you for the notes. I don't want to teach anyone bad habits, but I am also against kitchen recipes. Good programming comes from understanding.

Stackoverflow is literally a kitchen recipe repository, though. It's literally why it's gotten as big as it has. The main reason people use it is to find a quick answer so they can get back to what they were doing. So: good programming comes from good kitchen recipes on SO, with enough guide text to explain why they're good kitchen recipes for those who want to learn =)

I modified the answer, but I cannot agree with you on advocating. However, these arguments are even irrelevant: "advocating" is too social and philosophical category to fit the genre of these answers. You may be right that Stackoverflow is a kitchen recipe category, and this is a pity. I was a number 2 advisor on CodeProject by reputation and knew how bad it is, answering instead of helping. It feels like many good experts here are afraid of answering in a formal way, they only comment.

It's quite easy to look up someone's profile so you can trivially confirm they don't just comment but also practice what they preach (quite a number of folks in fact post quite a lot of excellent answers, but generally in a way that both "I just need code now" as well as people want to learn both get what they're looking for). In terms of your edit: you probably want to include the MDN link so that folks can go down the "authoritative" path of learning more about for...in, as comments aren't part of an answer (I periodically prune mine, as comments don't serve much purpose after edits)

I understand you, about commenting. I was talking about my impression. MDN links: I used to put many of them, but I started to think that the answer remains valid if it just gives comprehensive names of things, so the related documentation pages are easy to find. Note that for this question I already went out of scope pretty well, because even "not all objects can iterate via for.. of" would be quite enough — it answers the question. Instead of advising me to go out of scope even more, you could add your answer and explain that you are giving additional useful information. I would up-vote it.
